# Fail to open IndexedDB database within Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

what's wrong with this code in Google Chrome

```
r = webkitIndexedDB.open(db_name,1);
r.onsuccess = success_callback;
r.onerror = error_callback;
r.onupgradeneeded = function(e){
   var db = e.currentTarget.result;
   db.createObjectStore('os_name',{keyPath:id,autoIncrement:true});
};
```

it's works in firefox (mozIndexedDB) but not in chrome. even onerror won't be triggered. anyway i get this error

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3
```

Comment: deni has the correct answer here. please be sure to mark them as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onupgradeneeded` is not supported function in Google Chrome, instead you should use the `setversion` method for initiating the database in the beginning of `onsuccess` event on database opening as described here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/#toc-step2

Your code should look something like this:

```
r.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var v = "1.0";
    var db = e.currentTarget.result;
    // We can only create Object stores in a setVersion transaction;
    if(v!= db.version) {
      var setVrequest = db.setVersion(v);

      setVrequest.onfailure = error_callback;
      setVrequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var store = db.createObjectStore('os_name',{keyPath:id,autoIncrement:true});
        ...
      };
    }
    ...
}
```

Edit November 2013: This is a obsolete answer now, since Google Chrome only supports upgrade of the database with the `onupgradeneeded` event.